# Default raw added in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a `datagrid` control in `WPF` and user can add rows by double clicking on the last empty row , but the row inserted has default values, and I want to add some predefined values (defined in `XAML` if that is possible ) so for example I  have  a column date which is binded to date property of `ViewModel` and I would like that new added rows already have that value of the property date.
I have used `CollectionChanged` event of `ObservableCollection` which is binded to the `ItemSource` of `datagrid` but that it's not what I am looking for.

```
  public void ContentCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (WpfApp1.ViewModels.TimeSheetRow item in e.NewItems)
            {

                // Change properties values of the new row

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't set the default values of the properties of the data object in XAML. Why don't you do this in the contructor of the class? XAML is a *markup* language.

Comment: Taught that would be some kind of template and could bind to some properties

Comment: There is a `DataGridTemplateColumn` but it can't be used to set the default properties of the data object.

Comment: @mm8 Ok than I would do it in constructor, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the default values of the properties of the data object in XAML.

You should either do this in the contructor of the class, or by for example handling the `CollectionChanged` event of the source collection.